# Delete Firebase object with swipe

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swipe, android-viewholder

I wish to delete an object from Firebase on Swipe left. Everything works fine now with the swipe and it it removed from the view, but it stays in the database.

I've added the following to my onCreate:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
        Toast.makeText(ListBox.this, "Item removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
    }
};
```

and this is how i populate my ViewHolder.

```
@Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BoxViewHolder viewHolder, final Box model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            final String boxUniqueKey = model.getBoxkey();

            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Launch BoxItem view
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(ListBox.this, AddBoxItem.class);

                    String boxkey = model.getBoxkey();
                    String boxName = model.getTitle();

                    startActivity(intent);

                    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
                    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(allBoxes);

                }
            });
        }
```

but how (and where) do I get the position of the item, and how can I send the remove query to the Firebase Database?

Comment: You could give or cast to a `BoxViewHolder` within `onSwipe`. But you will need the ID or position of the data stored as part of `BoxViewHolder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have coded something very similar to what you are trying to achieve. This is one way you could achieve it.

First, extend the `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` class to make your own custom class.

```java
public class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

private RecyclerAdapter adapter; // this will be your recycler adapter

private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

/**
 * 
  Make sure you pass in your RecyclerAdapter to this class

 */
public CallBack(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerAdapter adapter) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // this is how you can get the position
    Object object = adapter.getObject(position); // You will have your own class ofcourse.

    // then you can delete the object
     root.child("Object").child(object.getId()).setValue(null);// setting the value to null will just delete it from the database.

}
```

Calling `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` returns the position of the view in the adapter. You can use this position to get the `Object` from the `ArrayList` contained in your recycler adapter.

In my adapter, I have created a `getObject` method. This just returns the object from the `ArrayList` that my adapter has. Once I have the object, I can call the associated Firebase Realtime Database method and delete the object. In my `Object` class, I have stored the unique key within the object so I can easily delete it. I get the unique id by calling `getId()`. I pass this to the associated Firebase Realtime Database method and set the value to `null` which deletes it.

After doing this you can add it to your recycler view like this.

```java
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback swipeToDeleteCallback = new
            SwipeToDeleteCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, choreRecyclerAdapter, getContext()); // Making the SimpleCallback

    ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback);

    touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView); // then attach it to your recycler view
```

First, you make a simple callback and make sure you instantiate the custom class that you extended. Be sure to pass your recycler adapter.

Notice I only support right swipe by passing `ItemTouchHelper.Right`. You can support left or pass in both left and right.

Then create an `ItemTouchHelper` object and pass it your simple callback.

Lastly, you attach your touch helper to your recycler view and that's all.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i wanted!